# How to download files that were marked as dependencies from Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

At the end of a build of ProjectA, the artifacts are uploaded to Artifactory with a jfrog CLI command like this one:

```
jfrog rt upload --build-name projectA --build-number 123 <artifacts-pattern> my-repo/ProjectA/123/
```

And then that build is published:

```
jfrog rt build-publish projectA 123
```

Later on I build ProjectB, for which I need to download the artifacts of ProjectA. I use the `--build-name` and `--build-number` arguments again, this time to mark the downloaded artifacts as dependencies of  the projectB build. (Originally I expected these arguments to select the build to download, but that was a misunderstanding. They only collect build info for the ongoing build.)

```
jfrog rt download --build-name projectB --build-number 456 my-repo/ProjectA/123/*
```

And then when the ProjectB build completes, I also upload the created artifacts

```
jfrog rt upload --build-name projectB --build-number 456 <artifacts-pattern> my-repo/ProjectB/456/
```

and publish that build as well:

```
jfrog rt build-publish projectB 456
```

If I now examine the build-info JSON of the projectB build number 456, I can see that the artifacts that I uploaded for ProjectB itself, and the dependencies downloaded from ProjectA have all been recorded with their hash and file name. So far so good.

The problem is now that I am looking for a command that will download the ProjectA artifacts that were dependencies of the ProjectB build. I tried to use this filespec:

```
{
    "files": 
    [
        {
            "pattern": "my-repo/projectA/*",
            "build": "projectB",
            "target": "./artifactory-tmp/"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this seemed to start downloading all projectA builds, instead of just the files that were associated with the latest ProjectB build. How do I get these dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JFrog CLI supports aggregating published builds. To download build's artifacts, run `jfrog rt dl --build=<buildName>/<buildNumber>`. If the build has an aggregated build, the aggregated build's artifacts will be downloaded too.

In your case, running the `jfrog rt build-append projectB 456 projectA 123` command before publishing projectB, will add projectA as a module of projectB.

Here how you can do it:

```
# Create and publish "projectA/123"
jfrog rt upload foo.zip generic-local --build-name projectA --build-number 1
jfrog rt build-publish projectA 123

# Create build "projectB/456"
jfrog rt upload bar.zip generic-local --build-name projectB --build-number 456

# Append published build "projectA/123" to build "projectB/456"
jfrog rt build-append projectB 456 projectA 123

# Publish "projectB/456"
jfrog rt build-publish projectB 456

# Download foo.zip and bar.zip
jfrog rt download --build=projectB/456
```

- This functionality is supported in JFrog CLI 1.45.0 and above.

Read more about build-append in the documentation under [Aggregating Published Builds](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-AggregatingPublishedBuilds).

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how the dependencies of projectA are associated to projectB (if it just through a build info or specific section or also additional properties were added), but if you are looking for more flexibility on which artifacts you want to download you can try to use [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language)

You can specify which artifacts you want to download and from which build id and number and if this dependency is used in a specific module or not.
If these dependencies has common properties you can try to download based on these criteria as well.

AQL can also be combined with file specs of course.